# Creating complex URLs with Wordpress permalink structure

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I'm trying to self-educate so I can have a more informed conversation for a WP site development spec I'm trying to create. Grateful for any answers to what I would like to accomplish.

I want to create a way for visitors to my Wordpress site to fill out contact information, which includes personal information, and for that information to be automatically captured and placed on a unique and complex URL that can be accessed by a web browser but that is highly unlikely to be discovered.  I am not sure how to do this using Wordpress' permalink structure and frankly don't understand enough about Wordpress and PHP to formulate a solution to my situation.

Here's a example.  Assume my new visitor is Fred Jones.  Fred Jones visits mycoolnewwpsite.com and fills out a standard contact form with his name, email, favorite song, whatever.  I would like Fred's information to be automatically placed into a separate page (possibly not a Wordpress page) and created under a very difficult-to-guess/hack URL.  So I don't want a URL like www.mycoolwpsite.com/users/fredjones.  I actually want something more like mycoolwpsite.com/z34,90)2#1lqpe~3.

Basically a URL that would be next to impossible for someone to guess or even want to hack.  But I do want the information to be available for quick access by a web browser if in fact I knew that specific URL.

I'm trying to figure out whether I can use some sort of custom permalink structure in Wordpress or whether there is some better solution to this.  The important thing is that I cannot use the standard log in for users that Wordpress has, but I also need to protect the data users are providing using a complex/randomly generated URL path.

Many thanks for any light you can shed!

Comment: Why not make it easy for everyone, Just use the WordPress standard login and it will make your life and your developers life way easier.

Comment: Because the funky URL is being linked to a qr code that is going to be scanned to reveal the member info. If it redirects to the wp login, the person scanning would need to know different logins. Just not possible for the use case.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress offers a really straightforward API for that: [endpoints](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint). See [this example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67044/73) or [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54612/73).

In your use case I would create an endpoint for the root named `result` or whatever and a callback listening to that endpoint. The actual form results should be stored in a custom, not public post type with the same title as the name of the sub-section of this endpoint. This way you could edit it later from the back-end.