# How to assign a Permalink to a Function

Tags: permalinks

In Drupal, you can assign a URI to a function that gets called, like this:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    return array(
        'custom_uri' => array(
            'page callback' => 'my_custom_function',
            [...]
        );
    );
}
```

This then tells Drupal to call the function `my_custom_function` whenever the url is `http://www.mysite.com/custom_uri`.

In Wordpress I'm trying to accomplish the same idea. I want to have a custom URI that somehow calls a function to render output.

From what I've found I can use [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) to turn a permalink into a query string and then check for the query string in my plugin. Going that route, how would I display my own content in the site's theme?

The other option I've seen is to do it via a shortcode, but then that means either the user generates a page or I do it programmatically (and then probably use WP_Rewrite to set up a custom permalink). This seems messy and I'd rather the user not have to worry about doing any work.

Are there any more options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an [endpoint](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51444/add-extra-parameters-after-permalink/51450#51450). That is a custom URL that will be handled by a callback.

Examples are [How can I use WordPress functions in my stylesheet?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54612/73) and [Is it possible to request several post types from a feed?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67044/73). See also [`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) and [A (Mostly) Complete Guide to the WordPress Rewrite API](http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api).